# Extending jQuery UI selectmenu and no selection events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am writing an extension to the jQuery UI widget called `selectmenu`.  When I create my own custom version, I find that I am no longer able to detect selection events.  I have reduced to a simple recreate shown here:

```
$(function() {
  $.widget("xyz.abc", $.ui.selectmenu, function(){
    // No change to default function
  });
  $("#mySelect").abc({width: 200}).on("selectmenuselect", function(event, ui) {
    console.log("Selection changed: %O", ui);
  });
});
```

and also available as [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qemelu/8/edit?html,js,output).

In my sample code, I am creating a new widget called `abc` that extends the out of the box `selectmenu`.  In this trivial example, I leave all as default (no changes or overrides).  When a selection change is made, no detection is logged to the console.  However, if I change the code back to using the original base widget, the selection is again detected.

```
$(function() {
  $("#mySelect").selectmenu({width: 200}).on("selectmenuselect", function(event, ui) {
    console.log("Selection changed: %O", ui);
  });
});
```

My desire is to have a change selection event detected on a custom widget extended from the base widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if one extends the `selectmenu` then events published by your extended widget have the name of your extended widget (converted to lowercase) in the event name.  For example, if I extend "selectmenu" with a widget called "myWidget" then the published events are named:

- `mywidgetselect`
- `mywidgetchange`
- etc etc

The default (for selectmenu) event names are:

- `selectmenuselect`
- `selectmenuchange`
- etc etc

Comment: Yup, I tried your jsbin, and it didn't work so I started playing with the namespace. Eventually realized I needed to click "run with js" (I prefer jsfiddle) and that it was working from the start.

Comment: Thanks, somehow in my testing with jsbin I'd left it in a working state.  Now it is consistent and shows the "broken" version again.  I too don't like "jsbin" but it is easier to setup for jQuery UI demos than jsFiddle (opinion).